# Error with ArrayType findAndRemove global function?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a global `findAndRemove` function for use with `ArrayType`s and have run into a problem. I am getting an error saying:

`Cannot convert the expression's type '0' to type '@lvalue Named'`

Here's the function...

```
func findAndRemove<C : ArrayType where C.GeneratorType.Element : Equatable>(var domain: C, value: C.GeneratorType.Element) {
  var idx = find(domain, value)
  if idx { domain.removeAtIndex(idx! as Int) }
}
```

Here's the accompanying, contrived code you can put into an Xcode playground...

```
class Named {
  let name: String
  init (_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

var arr = [Named("Fire"), Named("Water"), Named("Earth"), Named("Air")]
var fire = arr[0]

arr // Returns [Named("Fire"), Named("Water"), Named("Earth"), Named("Air")]
findAndRemove(&arr, fire) // <-- Error occurs here!!!
arr // Should return [Named("Water"), Named("Earth"), Named("Air")]
```

Don't worry that the example is pointless because I could just use `arr.removeAtIndex(0)`. This is a contrived example made to test `findAndRemove`.

Comment: your class (`Named`) does not conform to protocol `Euqatable`, however it has to, that is why you get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution would be with conforming the `Equatable` protocol:

```
class Named {  
    let name: String
    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Named : Equatable { }

func ==(lhs: Named, rhs: Named) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

---

now this furnction should work properly (with `inout` var instead):

```
func findAndRemove<C : ArrayType where C.GeneratorType.Element : Equatable>(inout domain: C, value: C.GeneratorType.Element) -> () {
    var idx = find(domain, value)
    if idx { domain.removeAtIndex(idx! as Int) }
}
```

---

I've just extended my answer with the final call as well:

```
var myArray: Array<Named> = [Named("Fire"), Named("Water"), Named("Earth"), Named("Air")]
var fire: Named = myArray[0]

findAndRemove(&myArray, value: fire)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `inout` modifier, since you're not reassigning the `arr` variable.